# Automation for updating AMI on services deployed on AWS codepipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, automation, aws-codepipeline

I am looking automate triggering the release change api interface in each pipeline for a specified date.

I tried using a script to automate the process, but it seems am not doing it right. The code is already deployed on AWS codepipeline.